# How to connect to a Docker container with credentials using command line?

Tags: database, tomcat, docker, command-line

I've pulled a database image using docker and set the needed database url and credentials in my context.xml file. However, I get an access denied error when starting Tomcat. So I would like to connect to this Docker container with the help of cmd.

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that your container is running.
So, use :

```
docker exec -t -i CONTAINER_NAME /bin/sh
```

Comment: I would add that one should detach the container properly when done (`Ctrl+P, Ctrl+Q`), to make sure that it does not exit.